# Compute the indefinite integral of a function whose primite is arccos

Tags: real-analysis, indefinite-integrals

While I was studying Kepler's first law, I encountered the following indefinite integral:
$$\int \frac{\lvert b \rvert}{x^2 \sqrt{-1+\frac{2a}{x}-\frac{b^2}{x^2}}}\,dx.$$
($a,b\in \Bbb{R}$, $\lvert b\rvert=\sqrt{b^2}$, $a^2-b^2>0$ and may assume $x>0$.)
It is claimed that, up to a constant (clearly), $\arccos\Bigl(\frac{b^2-ax}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\Bigr)$ is the primitive of the integrand.
An easy derivation confirms the assertion.
But I was not able to find the primitive by myself.
Can you help me to understand how such a computation should be handled, please?

Comment: I think the best method would be to complete the square in the denominator and go for a trig sub. (after all there is an $\arccos$ in the primitive) I'm trying that now and I think it's getting somewhere but I'll let you know in a second.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thank you. I tried to complete the square and put out of the square root $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$, but I got stuck anyway. I hope you are smarter than me.

Comment: I think it's worked, answer's on the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this goes through rigorously (feel free to yell at me in the comments) but this was my process:

First, complete the square in the denominator:
$$\sqrt{-1 + \dfrac{2a}{x} - \dfrac{b^2}{x^2}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}-1 - \dfrac{b^2}{x^2} + \dfrac{2a}{x} - \dfrac{a^2}{b^2}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{b^2}-\left(\dfrac{b^2}{x^2}-2\dfrac{b\cdot a}{x \cdot b} + \dfrac{a^2}{b^2}\right)} = \sqrt{\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{b^2}-\left(\dfrac{b^2-ax}{bx}\right)^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{|b|}\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{b^2-ax}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right)^2}$$

Plugging this into our integrand:
$$\int \dfrac{|b|}{x^2 \sqrt{-1 + \dfrac{2a}{x} - \dfrac{b^2}{x^2}}} dx = \int\dfrac{|b|^2}{x^2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{b^2-ax}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right)^2}}dx$$

Notice that by the linearity of absolute values, $|b|^2 = |b||b| = |b^2|$, and because $b^2$ is always nonnegative, $|b^2| = b^2$.

Now, introduce the trigonometric substitution:
$$\cos{\theta}=\dfrac{b^2-ax}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$

Differentiating on both sides:
$$-\sin{\theta} d\theta = \dfrac{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}(-a) - (b^2-ax)\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{x^2(a^2-b^2)}dx = \dfrac{-b^2}{x^2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}dx$$

Notice the similarity between this and our integrand's first fraction. Therefore:
$$\int\dfrac{b^2}{x^2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{b^2-ax}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right)^2}}dx = \int \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2{\theta}}} \cdot -\sin{\theta} d\theta$$

Now, supposing that $\sin\theta > 0$:
$$\int \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2{\theta}}} \cdot -\sin{\theta} d\theta = \int \dfrac{\sin\theta}{|\sin\theta|} d\theta = \int d\theta = \theta + C$$

By definition, $\cos\theta = \dfrac{b^2-ax}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$, so $\theta = \arccos\left(\dfrac{b^2-ax}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right)$.

$$\int \dfrac{|b|}{x^2 \sqrt{-1 + \dfrac{2a}{x} - \dfrac{b^2}{x^2}}} dx = \arccos\left(\dfrac{b^2-ax}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right) + C$$

I believe this works, I am a little unsure about the finer details of assuming $\sin\theta > 0$ and whether the use of $\arccos$ is appropriate, so there may be some details left which need to be filled in, but I would say that this is at least a solid motivation for the given primitive.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I must agree with you about the assumption $\sin \theta >0$.

Comment: Yesterday, I spent almost a day trying to compute the above integral, but I just now realize that the solution had been gained several times, though I didn't recognize it. It's enough to see how $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{b^2-ax}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$ looks like, and the result is almost immediate. With the above remark, your substitution is not necessary. Edit your answer, so that I can accept it. Just one more thing: if you know, can you tell me why to bring $x$ in the square root doesn't seem to work? Thank you very much for your help, @Stephen.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean. First, what edit are you suggesting for my answer? And where are you bringing the x in that's not working?

Comment: I try to explain what I mean (sorry for my english).

Comment: Stop reading before you make the substitution involving $\cos\theta$. You come up with a formula, andyou can notice that $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{b^2-ax}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}=\frac{-b^2}{x^2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$, which already appears in the integral, up to a minus sign. So the integral has the form $\int \frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1-f(x)^2}}\,dx= arccos\, f(x)$. Hope to be clear.

Comment: Well yes, but it was always my understanding that this is equivalent with the substitution. Basically one way you're arguing in terms of the chain rule, and the other way you're arguing in terms of a u-sub, which are essentially the same thing in opposite directions if you get my meaning.

Comment: Yes, I see. I'm not completely convinced, but I accept your answer anyway. Dear Stephen, thank you very much for your kind help. Have a good day :)

Comment: Thank you, you too. :)